# Opacity issues with text nested within divs

Tags: html, css, text, opacity, nested

I have three divs, one big parent div, one smaller box inside the parent, and then text inside of the smaller box.

```
<div class='parentDiv'>
    <div class='smallBox'>
        <div class='text'> Hello!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, the opacity of my 'Hello!' text is being faded to something that looks like .5; or 50%  I can't tell because I have nothing setting the opacity of any of these divs.

the Background-color of my ParentDiv and smallBox is set to : transparent; so you can see the text inside..  would the transparent background be affecting the opacity of the text? How can I fix this?

here is my css.

```
.parentDiv {
 width: 1020px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: Transparent;
 position: absolute;
 top: 450px;
}

.smallBox {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 160px;
}

.text{
font-family: robotolight, sans-seriff;
font-size: 18px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
left: 30px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100000;
width: 100px
margin: 0px auto;
line-height: 30px;

}
```

Comment: color: #ffffff; ?? any reason?

Comment: It is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/cpygpor8/

Comment: How are we supposed to tell?  You have the big box's background set to white, the small box has no background color, and the font color is also set to white.  Did you mean to set it to black?

Comment: aside from missing a semicolumn (;) after width :100px it is showing on all my browsers.
Only thing it is white text on white background...

Comment: Well that's why you can't see it, @AlexB.

Comment: the big box's background is not white, its transparent.  color#ffffff; is to color my text white.. If its working for everyone else then I really dont know... I guess I will just get rid of the .parentDiv and absolutely position the .text div by itself.

Comment: It is transparent, but in top of something, in our case is in top of background white of fiddle.

Comment: I didnt include my html, and body css which make my background darker. @TomerAlmog       thanks for pointing out the semi colon.

Comment: Any opacity on parent element? opacity is inherit in the sense that if a parent have 0.5 opacity than all of its descendents will have 0.5 opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts with a 'light' font-weight will look more faded due to their nature. Try changing fonts and see if it is still an issue.